# Rendering canvas script twice

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas with some ballons that I got from the internet, I need that to finish my job :).
Basically, I could use that canvas in one side of my page, but I need the canvas ballons on the other side, so I changed the

`<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`

**to**

`<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>`

and used the tag again in the section that I need, but that doesn't work, do you guys know how can I solve that problem?

Comment: We need more information to help you. How does the css for canvas looks like?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Gthibaud/pen/grvrYq i used this, just adapt for my code, i need to use it twice

Answer (score 0):

The sample that you've used is a sample script handling a single canvas. It is not abstracted and lots of its variables and methods are in the global scope. So short of refactoring that code to be able to handle multiple canvases (requires at least encapsulating the functionality into some wrapper that applies it to a particular canvas passed as a parameter), you may include this application as iframes.

- create an a simple page that only displays a canvas full-screen.
- to your parent page add iframes with the ballon page as a source.

> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>     <iframe src="ballons.html" height=300 width=300></iframe>
>     <iframe src="ballons.html" height=300 width=300></iframe>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: just a question friend, this is just to be preety code reuse and preety is not the main thing here, so if i create 2 scripts like that baloon script, can i use each 1 in a different canvas? and how, cause i tryed and 1 doesnt show correctly

Comment: It will not work like that. Given script create lots of global variables. 2nd same scripts will overwrite such variables, and they share the namespace of your page. Script needs to be refactored to  be able to handle 2 canvases. Using iframes is exactly what you wanted, just try it.